# Reverting to the original prompt in PowerShell Console

Tags: function, powershell

In PowerShell console window the initial prompt is

```
C:\users\username
```

I could customize the prompt with the below:

```
function Prompt { "PS: "}
```

The prompt now becomes

```
PS:
```

Without making change to the C:\Users\user\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 I intend to revert to the original prompt.

How to go about it?

Comment: `function Prompt { "PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) " }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the `about_Prompt` help file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Prompts):

> In Windows PowerShell 3.0, the built-in prompt function is:
>
> ```
> function prompt  
> {  
>     "PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) "  
> }
> ```

Comment: I see that with below method I could revert back to the original prompt without having to remember the long script..

**`function my_prompt = (Get-Command Prompt).scriptblock`**_Then I could revoke the function my_prompt to revert to the original prompt_